# Facebook like input box which supports user mentions and hashtags using react-native

Tags: react-native, user-input, hashtag, react-native-textinput

I am working on a feature. I need to show the hashtags and user mentions in blue color inside the TextInput, and when I delete the user mentions and hashtags entire word should be deleted just like facebook. I also need to display the user suggestions and hashtag suggestions.

I have already tried the below available libraries but those are not able to serve the exact requirement :

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-mentions
2. https://github.com/mrazadar/react-native-mentions-editor
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-controlled-mentions

Problem : Not able to maintain the user information while displaying the Username name (First Name + Last Name ) and editing it as I need to send the data in specific format.